# How can I use draftjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use Facebook's draftjs components ，But I encountered some obstacles 。

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Editor, EditorState } from 'draft-js';

class MyEditor extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()
    };
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({ editorState });
}

render(){
        var {editorState} = this.state;
        return(
            <Editor editorState={ editorState } onChange={ this.onChange } />
        );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
      <MyEditor />,
      document.getElementById('container')
);
```

This is the code I wrote ，but=>

```
Warning: A component is `contentEditable` and contains `children` managed by React. It is now your responsibility to guarantee that none of those nodes are unexpectedly modified or duplicated. This is probably not intentional.


console.error(message);
```

I changed the code as follows, and succeeded =>

```
render(){
        var {editorState} = this.state;
        return(
            <div>富文本编辑器</div>
        );
}
```

[image]

But this is the reason why?

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in react 15.0.0 [Link](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/6112).